# Enchant Which Weapon Property: % Attack Speed or % Damage

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

As a Barbarian who is mainly playing WW build, I don't know which I should prioritize on:  weapon damage, IAS or % Damage?

This is the item I got:

[image]

Comment: I just want to note that in this specific example, the +10% damage is actually useful since the damage is physical. If it had been, say, "+1192-1418 **Fire** Damage" on the weapon instead, that +10% damage wouldn't be doing much for you because there's a bug that keeps it from adding to a weapon's elemental damage bonus. In that case, +% damage would be the clear choice of property to reroll for enchanting.

Comment: @Sterno Except that that's been a confirmed bug.  That damage should be (and will, hopefully soon) applied to the fire damage.

Comment: [Recent Blizzard post](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12329613352?page=9#164) confirming a fix soon™.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Arqade ! Even though those questions can be answered here, I would advise you to take a first look (and ask a question) on the official Blizzards' Barbarian forum (Either [the US one](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/3354996/) or [the European one](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/2823157/). Those community are rather active and truly focused on playing barb so you might get quicker and better answer from there :D Cheers and good luck with the reroll

Comment: @Doc I disagree on the dupe, playign bar or playing DH is not the same. Even if we were talkign about the same class, the answer still depends on your build, skill level, other gear and personnal preference. I don't think you can actually get a general answer for those question

Comment: @WizLiz Either we mark as dup, or we close for being too specific, otherwise we'll have a new question for every class and every build if you try to make that be the difference

Comment: @Doc "Too Specific" is not a reason listed in close vote. This issue has already been discussed [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8212/how-to-deal-with-how-should-one-counter-x-questions-in-moba) for MOBA and question like "How to counter a specific character", you might want to take a look at it.

Comment: @WizLiz It's not listed, but Too Specific really is a close reason. We don't want broad, overly vague questions because they're not detailed enough, but by the same token, we don't want questions that only help a single person. That said, I think this is duped properly. We only need one question about IAS vs. +% damage.

Comment: @Frank Fair enough, I'll edit the other post to make a more general answer

Answer (score 4):

The answer is always, **it depends**.

If you want more hits in a given amount of time, for instance you are running blood thirst and want to expend fury faster for healing, then you want the IAS.

If you want to hit harder per strike with WW or if you want to expend less fury while spinning, then you want the damage.

Generally, WW is probably not your only kill skill and you'll have other non 'channeled' type skills such as hota, and those all feed off of weapon damage rather than ias so most likely you'll want to keep the damage % instead of ias.

Answer (score 2):

I just calculated this, and in raw numbers the % DMG wins, here the calculation:

The Average DMG of the weapon is (1659 + 2203) / 2 = **1931**

**Removing %DMG (Keeping attack Speed)**

If we remove the 10%+DMG we have to divide 1931 by 1.1    1931 / 1.1 = 1755.45
Now for the DPS we have to Multiply the attack speed: 1755.45 x 1.28 = **2246.98**

So 2246.98 is the DPS we get when we remove % DMG and keep %AS

**Removing AS (Keeping % DMG)**

for the AS remove we divide our attack speed by 1.07: 1.28 / 1.07 = 1.19(actually Echoing Fury has 1.20 AS but who cares)
and now we multiply it with the avg. DPS: 1931 x 1.19 = **2309.98**

**Conclusion**

% DMG is clearly better in this case, you don't just get roughly 60 Weapon-DPS when keeping the DMG, you also spend less ressource for your abilities as if you would keep the attack speed.

The only case where you should keep the attack speed is when you play a build which depends on getting as many ppm(procs per minute) as possible and as far i can remember, there is no such (viable) build.

**Go for the %DMG!**

Comment: I'm confused, your numbers show that keeping the % damage wins but you state keep the IAS wins?

Comment: I totally mixed that up, sorry for that, i edited it to be correct!

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend that you prioritize the +% damage.

Imagine it was 7% damage vs 7% IAS.
- They both would give you the same DPS overall
- But the IAS would spend 7% more fury to do so by hitting faster for less.

So the +Dmg deals the same amount of damage in the same amount of time, using less fury.

Like z- said, maybe you want to spend more fury because you heal with blood thirst.

**However... 10 > 7**
And +Dmg is more efficient than +IAS